# Get Windows Eventlog entries by a date in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to filter eventlogs in PowerShell by a date range. When I run the command, it shows every event log by the entry type that I give. What am I doing wrong?

`Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error -Before 12/1/19 -After 12/3/19`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. Powershell 5.

By the logic of your question you want the entries except for 12/02 but I am including two methods in case your question was wrong.

powershell get-eventlog by specific date:

```
Get-EventLog System -Entrytype Error | Where-Object TimeWritten -Like "12/02/2019*"
```

or:

powershell get-eventlog before date and after date:

```
Get-EventLog System -Entrytype Error -Before 12/01/2019 -After 12/03/2019
```